# SVN remove local files, retain in repository

Tags: svn, version-control

So here's a question that I haven't seen asked.

Im using subversion 1.7

I did an "svn co" on a directory that I do not need, but cannot be removed from the repository (other people DO need it). I can delete the local copy of the directory and that is fine, but when I run "svn up" on the root up restores the deleted directory.

```
  /rootDir
        /folder1.      
        /unneededFolder
```

I can delete unneededFolder but svn keeps trying to restore it when I run update on the rootDir (rather than having to run svn up on each subdirectory). How can I tell svn to stop updating that folder in my working copy without deleting it from the repository?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to do is to use:

`svn update --set-depth exclude <dir>`

This will remove  from your working copy, but leave it in the repository.

See documentation on [Sparse Directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html).

Answer (score 0):

The option `-N` on `svn update` will cause the update to be non-recursive; and only the stuff in your current working directory will be updated.

Comment: The -N option is marked as deprecated. You should use --depth=..instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use the --depth Option of the svn client (sparse-checkout called). This means you have to do a separate checkout using the --depth option to limit the number of directory levels which will be checked out. Which means in your case:

```
svn co URL rootDir --depth=immediate
```

than you have a working copy which does not contain all levels. Now you can go to the directories you would like to have all levels or limited levels. Let's assume you go to folder1:

```
svn update --depth=infinity
```

so after that you will not get the contents of the unneededFolder unless you go into that folder and do an:

```
svn update --depth=infinity
```

The trade-off is that you can NOT go back if you did a infinity once.

Furthermore you are talking about the repository but you mean the working copy.

Comment: Thank you.
I had actually done more or less as you indicated, only checking out the immediates from the root directory, and then using "svn update" as appropriate.

What I learned from this is that you can't "undo" an "svn update" on a folder. Once you've updated it once, there is no way to remove it from your local copy AND prevent it from returning in an "svn update" at the root dir.

The way to fix it then is to completely remove the local copy and re-checkout the root dir and update the folders I need.

Thansk!